# Unable to launch Chrome on Mac using selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, macos, google-chrome, selenium

I want to run my script on MAC Chrome. I performed following steps

1. Download latest chrome driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. Unzip the package and then copy the file to /usr/bin

**On irb i excuted following steps**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

It gives following error message

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1406:in `block in transport_request'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `catch'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `transport_request'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1376:in `request'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `block in request'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
        from /Users/vertis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from (irb):4
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info on your environment. What version of osx, version of ruby, version of chrome and lastly version of chromedriver for selenium(I'm assuming 2.9). I am running osx 10.8.5, ruby 2.1.0, chrome 33.0 and chromedriver for selenium 2.9 **but** I do not see the same issue you are running into.

Comment: MAC OSX 10.9.1,  Chrome 33.0, Ruby 2.0.0p247, chromedriver 2.9

Comment: Good old Mavericks, I will upgrade tonight and let you know what I run into.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Even after upgrading this evening and testing your steps this morning I am unable to reproduce. Sorry for not being able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

download latest version of chromedriver and keep it in usr/local/bin and run your code it will work because same thing works for me....if you want to see which version is running then go to your chromedriver and right click and open with terminal. it will show you the version so please keep this in mind that your version should be something 2.15.XXXXXX

and i am pretty sure it will work for you!

Comment: No it doesn't. The same problem, modern versions, nothing helps.